# Plasmid transformation yields only empty vectors

Tags: molecular-biology, lab-techniques, experimental-design, cloning

I have to electroporate pMAD cloned with an insert of 7.4 kb in my *S. aureus* isolate. When I electroporated in RN4220 I had no problems but when I put it in my isolate I just recover few colonies and they have the empty plasmid. Has anyone had this problem?

Comment: How do you know they're empty? Are you doing blue-white screening or actually isolating the plasmid?

Comment: I ask because if your isolate contains an endogenous beta-galactosidase gene, blue-white screening will not work.

Comment: I have the primers to amplifie the region of the multiple cloning sites and it gives me the fragment of an empty plasmid. Also I cut the plasmid with the same enzymes of the cloning and it gives me no fragment of the insert size, only the empty plasmid. When I do the same thing with the plasmids from RN4220, I have the good fragments...

Comment: A qualified guess is that either your insert is somehow toxic to the cells or you have a contamination issue with the empty plasmids far outweighing your plasmid with the insert concentration wise.